# PL/SQL procedure to assign grades to the employees

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-update, database-cursor

```
create or replace procedure p2
as
    CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT salary
      FROM   employee1
      FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
FOR employee_rec IN c1 LOOP
exit when c1%notfound;
if salary>20000 then
update employee1 set grade='A' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
if salary>15000 then
update employee1 set grade='B' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
if salary>10000 then
update employee1 set grade='C' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
if salary<10000 then
update employee1 set grade='D' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
end if;
end if;
end if;
end if;
END LOOP;
END p2;
```

An error shows up as **salary is undeclared** How can I make this code better to get the desired output???

Comment: Why are you using such a slow and inefficient way to do this? You can do this with a much more efficient **single** UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because there is no variable `salary`. You have a cursor called `employee_rec` which contains a column called `salary` but you would need to reference that using `employee_rec.salary`.

If we fix that (and indent your code) then it compiles:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE p2 AS
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT salary
    FROM   employee1
    FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR employee_rec IN c1 LOOP
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

    IF employee_rec.salary>20000 THEN
      update employee1 set grade='A' WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
      IF employee_rec.salary>15000 THEN
        update employee1 set grade='B' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
        IF employee_rec.salary>10000 THEN
          update employee1 set grade='C' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
          IF employee_rec.salary<10000 THEN
            update employee1 set grade='D' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END p2;
/
```

However, it isn't going to give you the output you want due to the nested `IF` statements. If you replace the nested `IF` statements with `ELSIF`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2 AS
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT salary
    FROM   employee1
    FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR employee_rec IN c1 LOOP
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

    IF employee_rec.salary>20000 THEN
      update employee1 set grade='A' WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
    ELSIF employee_rec.salary>15000 THEN
      update employee1 set grade='B' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
    ELSIF employee_rec.salary>10000 THEN
      update employee1 set grade='C' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
    ELSIF employee_rec.salary<10000 THEN
      update employee1 set grade='D' WHERE  CURRENT OF c1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END p2;
/
```

Then your procedure works (except when the salary is 10,000).

However, you could still make it more efficient by getting rid of the cursor:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2 AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE employee1
  SET grade = CASE
              WHEN salary > 20000 THEN 'A'
              WHEN salary > 15000 THEN 'B'
              WHEN salary > 10000 THEN 'C'
                                  ELSE 'D'
              END;
END p2;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a60c028c84a25dade32746bcc32a773d)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply like this:

```
update employee1 set grade= 
case 
   when salary>20000 then 'A'
   when salary>15000 then 'B'
   when salary>10000 then 'C'
   when salary<10000 then 'D'
   ELSE grade -- keep existing grade value
end;
```

Comment: `WHEN salary=10000 THEN NULL`. You want `<=` or `ELSE`.

Comment: @MT0, question states `if salary<10000 then update employee1 set grade='D'`. But yes, an `ELSE` case should be included.

Answer (score 0):

It is not

```
if salary>20000 then
```

but

```
if employee_rec.salary>20000 then
```

---

Code you wrote can be simplified - up to a single `UPDATE` statement. However, if you're using PL/SQL for learning, `CASE` is probably a better option than nested `IF`s. Something like this example based on subset of Scott's `EMP` table.

Test data:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    select empno, ename, sal, 'x' grade
  3    from emp
  4    where deptno = 10;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test order by sal desc;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL G
---------- ---------- ---------- -
      7839 KING             5000 x
      7782 CLARK            2450 x
      7934 MILLER           1300 x
```

Procedure, testing & result:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p2 as
  2    cursor c1 is select sal from test for update;
  3  begin
  4    for employee_rec in c1 loop
  5      update test set
  6        grade = case when employee_rec.sal  > 3000 then 'A'
  7                     when employee_rec.sal  > 2000 then 'B'
  8                     when employee_rec.sal  > 1000 then 'C'
  9                     when employee_rec.sal <= 1000 then 'D'
 10                end
 11      where current of c1;
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p2;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test order by sal desc;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL G
---------- ---------- ---------- -
      7839 KING             5000 A
      7782 CLARK            2450 B
      7934 MILLER           1300 C

SQL>
```

Comment: What about grade 'D'?

Comment: Nothing, @Wernfried. Nobody is paid that low. Just kidding. I just didn't put it into that code.

Comment: Maybe it is the hourly rate :-)

Comment: Well, that depends on currency, @Wernfried. 10.000 per hour sounds great if it is EUR or USD. Doesn't look that well if it were Venezuelan bolívar :(